# Cutlist -> Frame Ranges for Loop/Trim

Tags: avisynth

How do I convert a cutlist of

```
 start: hours:minutes:seconds:milliseconds
 end: hours:minutes:seconds:milliseconds

 start1: hours:minutes:seconds:milliseconds
 end1: hours:minutes:seconds:milliseconds

 ...
```

into frames ranges for

```
Loop(0,start,end)
```

or

```
Trim
```

?

I tried

```
((milliseconds/100)+seconds+(minutes * 60)+(hours*3600))*framerate
```

but this cuts at the wrong position.

Answer (score 0):

Milliseconds are a thousandth of a second. Your code looks fine otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

As it was noted, one second has 1000 millisecond. Another problem you get is integer division, what means `milliseconds / 1000` will always yield zero.

So I think this should be the correct expression:

```
round(((float(milliseconds)/1000)+seconds+(minutes * 60)+(hours*3600))*framerate)
```